# help me in solving

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations, binomial-theorem

evaluate : 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{2+4k}
$$
I tried using pre formulated series of multinomial expansions but it doesnt help. Please give  a solution to the problem, without using complex numbers

Comment: nc2+nc6+....so on

Comment: Do you mean $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{2+4k}$ ?

Comment: yes @robjohn i meant that

Comment: I will update the MathJax in your question, but please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another idea.

Let $E_r(n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{r+4k}$ for $r=0,1,2,3$ and note $E_0(0)=1, E_1(0)=E_2(0)=E_3(0)=0$

We have the recurrences based on the formation of Pascal's triangle: $$E_0(n+1)=E_3(n)+E_0(n), E_1(n+1)=E_0(n)+E_1(n), E_2(n+1)=E_1(n)+E_2(n), E_3(n+1)=E_2(n)+E_3(n)$$

It is easy to prove by induction that $$E_1(n)+E_2(n)+E_3(n)+E_4(n)=2^n$$ and for $n\ge 1,$$$ E_1(n)+E_3(n)=E_0(n)+E_2(n)=2^{n-1}$$

So for $n\ge 1,$ $$ E_3(n)=2^{n-1}-E_1(n) \text{ and } E_0(n)=2^{n-1}-E_2(n)$$

So we have $$E_1(n+1)=2^{n-1}-E_2(n)+E_1(n)$$

and

$$E_2(n+1)=E_2(n)+E_1(n)$$ which is $$E_1(n)=E_2(n+1)-E_2(n)$$

Whence $$E_2(n+2)-E_2(n+1)=2^{n-1}-E_2(n)+E_2(n+1)-E_2(n)$$

This becomes the linear recurrence

$$E_2(n+2)=2E_2(n+1)-2E_2(n)+2^{n-1}$$ and the auxiliary equation is $$x^2-2x+2=0$$ which has roots $x=1\pm i$

Solving the recurrence with a particular solution for the inhomogeneous version plus a general solution for the homogeneous part, and then checking boundary conditions, gives the same elements as other solutions, and it is no surprise that the this method gives components $(1\pm i)^n$ and a multiple of $2^n$.

Comment: Thanks in advance for all these efforts

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For integer $n>0,\binom nr=0$ for $r<0,r>n$

So, we need $$\sum_{r=0,4r+2<n}\binom n{4r+2}$$

Now,
$$(1+y)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nry^r\  \ \ \ \  (1)\implies y^2(1+y)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nry^{r+2}\  \ \ \ \  (2)$$

If $y^4=1, y=\pm1,\pm i$

set $y=\pm1,\pm i$ in $(ii)$ and add

Comment: not satisfied i wanted without complex identities

Comment: @ChenGuo: Then state the question more precisely. I see that you've updated your question, but people have put in time answering your question only to have you change it under them. You should also add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). The lack of context is probably why people are voting to close this question. I've deleted my answer, but I will undelete it if more context is shown (what you've tried, where the question came from, etc.).

Comment: @ChenGuo: Also, you should use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to better format the math in your question.

Comment: @ChenGuo: The final answer can be expressed without complex numbers, but the derivation of that answer would be very complex without using complex numbers.

Comment: ok just thinking for a way to do that without i or omega

Answer (score 0):

I've made this more an extended hint and tried to give a different way into understanding lab bhattacharjee's method. I think of this as twisting a power series to get the right cancellations.

If $\omega$ is a complex $q^{th}$ root of unity we have that the sum $$S=1+\omega^r+\omega^{2r}+\dots +\omega^{(q-1)r}$$is equal to $q$ or $0$ according to whether $r$ is a multiple of $q$ or not. We can use this to pick out every $q^{th}$ element of a power series.

Here we would do $$(1+1)^n+(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n+\dots+(1+\omega^{(q-1)r})^n$$

This would pick out terms $0,q,2q,3q \dots$

If you want to pick out the terms $k, q+k \dots$ you have to shift the power series to get the right cancellation. But the same idea works.

---

Here you want to have $4^{th}$ roots of unity and shift so that the coefficient is non-zero only when $r\equiv 2 \bmod 4$

---

Comment: can u show me any idea to proceed without using i or complex numbers?

Comment: @ChenGuo I can't think of an easy way to do that, but I'll see what I can think of

Comment: @ChenGuo I have done this via recurrence relations in another solution, but that essentially leads to the same thing by another root.

Comment: I wondered if there is any series of omega or i....lol

Comment: I just want to escape writing i or omega